# C++ Program is too slow and doesnt seem to work?

Tags: c++, numbers

I'm working on a school project in which we must find the number of prime numbers between two numbers and even though I think the code is correct when I compile it and run it it doesn't show any results no matter how much time has passed
Is there something wrong with the code itself or is my computer just slow?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()

{

int x = 3;
int i = 1990000001;
int b = x^2;
int c = 0 ;
int d = 0 ;
    
while (i < 2000000000 ) {
    
     x=3;

    
    while ( b < i) {
        
        c = i % x ;
    
        if ( c = 0 )  {
        
        i+=2 ;
        break;
    }
        else {
            
        x += 2;
    }
    }
    
    
    if ( b>i ) {
    
       if ( c != 0){
       
        d+=1;
    
        i+=2;
     }
     } 
     
    else 
    i+=2; 
    
    
    
}


cout << "Prime numbers " << d << endl;

 }
```

Comment: You know that the `^` operator is the [*bitwise exclusive or* operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)?

Comment: And you do know that the `=` operator is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator? There are multiple, fundamental bugs in the shown code, besides these. The best thing for you to do is to: 1) use proper, logical indentation that will make some of these bugs quite obvious, 2) spend some time with a good C++ book.

Comment: while ( b < i) is an infinite loop, you never increment b which I assume is incorrectly initialized with a bitwise operator

Comment: @Martina. Consider adding meaningful comments to your code. In addition, your algorithm is somehow, not clear enough. Take a look at this link [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/prime-number-program-in-cpp)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of bugs.

While the code is nearly there, first your code is quite messy and your assignment operators are totally wrong, in C++

(C = 0) means: set the value of C to 0 in all cases

(C == 0) means: check the value C is equal to 0

More can be learned here.

> http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

To answer your question I have created a solution below in repl.it for you to test in their programming IDE. the second link below is the tutorial its created from, I would suggest you read it to gain a better understanding of the code.

> https://repl.it/@ryan122/FragrantPlumpDistributionsoftware

> https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/prime-number-intervals

To finish, I suggest looking up thenewboston's C++ youtube tutorials
:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvC1WCdV1XU

I **strongly** suggest you watch all his videos, they are very easy to learn and in small chunks.